# Spring Cloud Gateway - Intercept under hood request/response to Keycloak IDP

Tags: spring, keycloak, spring-webflux, spring-cloud-gateway, spring-session

We are implementing a Spring Cloud Gateway application (with Webflux) that is mediating the OAuth2 authentication with Keycloak.

SCG checks if the Spring Session is active: if not, redirects to Keycloak login page and handles the response from the IDP. This process is executed out-of-the-box by the framework itself.

Our needs is to intercept the IDP Keycloak response in order to retrieve a field from the response payload.

Do you have any advices that will help us to accomplish this behavior?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can implement `ServerAuthenticationSuccessHandler`:

```java
@Component
public class AuthenticationSuccessHandler implements ServerAuthenticationSuccessHandler {

    private ServerRedirectStrategy redirectStrategy;
    
    public AuthenticationSuccessHandler(AuthenticationService authenticationService) {
        redirectStrategy = new DefaultServerRedirectStrategy();

    }

    @Override
    public Mono<Void> onAuthenticationSuccess(WebFilterExchange webFilterExchange, Authentication authentication) {
        if(authentication instanceof OAuth2AuthenticationToken) {
            //Your logic here to retrieve oauth2 user info
        }
        ServerWebExchange exchange = webFilterExchange.getExchange();
        URI location = URI.create(httpRequest.getURI().getHost());
        return redirectStrategy.sendRedirect(exchange, location);
    }

}
```

And update your security configuration to include success handler:

```java
@Configuration
public class SecurityConfiguration {

    private AuthenticationSuccessHandler authSuccessHandler;

    public SecurityConfiguration(AuthenticationSuccessHandler authSuccessHandler) {
        this.authSuccessHandler = authSuccessHandler;
    }
    
    @Bean
    SecurityWebFilterChain securityWebFilterChain(ServerHttpSecurity http) {
        http
            .authorizeExchange(exchange -> exchange
            //other security configs
                    .anyExchange().authenticated()
                    .and()
                    .oauth2Login(oauth2 -> oauth2
                            .authenticationSuccessHandler(authSuccessHandler)

                    );

        return http.build();
    }
}
```